# Preview SwiftUI code in Playground on different devices

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-playground

XCode with can preview SwiftUI code on Canvas for many environments and devices with the help of `PreviewProvider`.
Like this:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            .environment((\.horizontalSizeClass), .compact)
            ContentView()
             .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(stringLiteral: "iPad8,5"))
             .environment((\.horizontalSizeClass), .regular)
        }
    }
}
```

How can we do the same in Playground? The following `.previewDevice()` modifier has no effect in Playground (XCode 12.0.1).

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(stringLiteral: "iPhone 7")))
```

Maybe it can be done somehow with `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` or else?

Comment: I believe you can't use it in Playground. It is for Xcode Preview canvas.