# external macro implementation type 'PreviewsMacros.SwiftUIView' could not be found for macro 'Preview(_:body:)' #Preview

Tags: swiftui, swift-macro

I am using macOS Ventura and Xcode 15.0.1. I have reached out to the original developer, but he does not get the same errors as I get. The code is supposed to create a button. I have tried googling of course, but to no avail. I don't know much about new Swift macros, so I am a bit lost as to what the problem might be. I should also say I am fairly new to SwiftUI, but I am learning every day.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> error: MyPlayground.playground:191:1: error: external macro implementation type 'PreviewsMacros.SwiftUIView' could not be found for macro 'Preview(_:body:)'
> #Preview {

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Custom Button Style

struct MobileMeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
   // MARK: Metrics
   @ScaledMetric private var cornerRadius = 12
   @ScaledMetric private var horizontalLabelPadding = 12
   @ScaledMetric private var verticalLabelPadding = 8
   @ScaledMetric private var shadowRadius = 2
   @ScaledMetric private var shadowVerticalOffset = 1

   // MARK: Immutable Properties
   private let strokeLineWidth = 1.0

   func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
      configuration.label
         .labelStyle(.mobileMe)
         .padding(.horizontal, horizontalLabelPadding)
         .padding(.vertical, verticalLabelPadding)
         .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
               .foregroundStyle(
                  LinearGradient(
                     colors: [
                        Color(red: 58/255, green: 63/255, blue: 66/255),
                        Color(red: 58/255, green: 63/255, blue: 66/255),
                        Color(red: 73/255, green: 76/255, blue: 80/255)
                     ],
                     startPoint: .top,
                     endPoint: .bottom
                  )
               )
               .overlay(
                  // Top reflection
                  ReflectionContainer {
                     UnevenRoundedRectangle(
                        cornerRadii: .init(
                           topLeading: cornerRadius,
                           bottomLeading: (cornerRadius * 0.43).rounded(.down),
                           bottomTrailing: (cornerRadius * 0.43).rounded(.down),
                           topTrailing: cornerRadius
                        ),
                        style: .continuous
                     )
                     .foregroundStyle(
                        LinearGradient(
                           colors: [
                              Color.white,
                              Color.white.opacity(0.24)
                           ],
                           startPoint: .top,
                           endPoint: .bottom
                        )
                     )
                     .blendMode(.plusLighter)
                     .opacity(0.24)
                  }
               )
               .overlay(
                  // Inner light stroke
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                     .strokeBorder(
                        LinearGradient(
                           colors: [
                              Color.white,
                              Color.white.opacity(0.2),
                              Color.white.opacity(0.24)
                           ],
                           startPoint: .top,
                           endPoint: .bottom
                        ),
                        lineWidth: strokeLineWidth
                     )
                     .blendMode(.plusLighter)
                     .opacity(0.3)
               )
               .overlay(
                  // Outer shadow stroke
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                     .inset(by: -strokeLineWidth)
                     .strokeBorder(
                        LinearGradient(
                           colors: [
                              Color.black.opacity(0.8),
                              Color.black
                           ],
                           startPoint: .top,
                           endPoint: .bottom
                        ),
                        lineWidth: strokeLineWidth
                     )
                     .opacity(0.34)
               )
         )
         .shadow(
            color: .black.opacity(0.2),
            radius: shadowRadius,
            x: 0,
            y: shadowVerticalOffset
         )
         .padding(.leading, 2)
         .environment(\.buttonRole, configuration.role)
   }
}

// MARK: - Custom Layout

private struct ReflectionContainer: Layout {
   func sizeThatFits(
      proposal: ProposedViewSize,
      subviews: Subviews,
      cache: inout ()
   ) -> CGSize {
      let safeProposal = proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions()
      return CGSize(width: safeProposal.width, height: safeProposal.height)
   }

   func placeSubviews(
      in bounds: CGRect,
      proposal: ProposedViewSize,
      subviews: Subviews,
      cache: inout ()
   ) {
      subviews.first!.place(
         at: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY),
         proposal: .init(
            width: proposal.width ?? 0,
            height: (proposal.height ?? 0) / 1.85
         )
      )
   }
}

// MARK: - Custom Label Style

private struct MobileMeLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
   // MARK: Environment
   @Environment(\.buttonRole) private var role

   // MARK: Metrics
   @ScaledMetric private var shadowRadius = 2
   @ScaledMetric private var shadowVerticalOffset = 1

   func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
      HStack {
         configuration.icon
         configuration.title
      }
      .font(.callout.weight(.medium))
      .foregroundStyle(
         role == .destructive
         ? AnyShapeStyle(Color.red.gradient)
         : AnyShapeStyle(Color.white.gradient.opacity(0.9))
      )
      .shadow(
         color: .black.opacity(role == .destructive ? 0.3 : 0.6),
         radius: shadowRadius,
         x: 0,
         y: shadowVerticalOffset
      )
   }
}

// MARK: - Quality Of Life

extension ButtonStyle where Self == MobileMeButtonStyle {
   static var mobileMe: Self { MobileMeButtonStyle() }
}

extension LabelStyle where Self == MobileMeLabelStyle {
   static var mobileMe: Self { MobileMeLabelStyle() }
}

// MARK: - Environment Extensions

private enum ButtonRoleEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
   static let defaultValue: ButtonRole? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
   var buttonRole: ButtonRole? {
      get { self[ButtonRoleEnvironmentKey.self] }
      set { self[ButtonRoleEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
   }
}

// MARK: - Preview

#Preview {
   HStack {
      Button(action: {}) {
         Label(
            title: { Text("Today") },
            icon: { EmptyView() }
         )
      }
      Button(role: .destructive, action: {}) {
         Label(
            title: { EmptyView() },
            icon: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
         )
      }
   }
   .padding(.horizontal, 16)
   .padding(.vertical, 16)
   .background(
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
         .foregroundStyle(
            LinearGradient(
               colors: [
                  Color(red: 72/255, green: 77/255, blue: 81/255),
                  Color(red: 46/255, green: 48/255, blue: 54/255)
               ],
               startPoint: .top,
               endPoint: .bottom
            )
         )
   )
   .buttonStyle(.mobileMe)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an Xcode Playground. Xcode Playgrounds don't support SwiftUI previews. ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64389585/5133585))

Xcode Playgrounds have *live views*, which also allow you to "preview" a SwiftUI view. This is slightly different to SwiftUI Previews, e.g. you cannot choose different devices - the view is sort of just displayed "in a vacuum".

Rather than using Xcode Playgrounds, you can create a new Xcode project, and paste the code there. Open the "Canvas" if it doesn't appear automatically:

[image]

Alternatively, if you do want to preview this in an Xcode playground, `import PlaygroundSupport` and change

```
#Preview {
    ...
}
```

to

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    ...
)
```

[Manually open the live view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33543460/5133585) if it is not open already. It'd look something like this:

[image]

---

Note that there is a similarly-named app called Swift Playgrounds, which [does support SwiftUI Previews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift-playgrounds/live-preview).

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, thanks for replying so quickly. I tried it in a project and got a different message. Not sure if this is progress or not LOL.  

 == PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme ”button2”
    
    linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    
    Link button2 (arm64):
    ld: Undefined symbols:
      _main, referenced from:
          <initial-undefines>
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @AndrewMead That really seems like an Xcode bug. I have no idea what would lead to that error. Try using the old [`PreviewProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previewprovider) API. If that also doesn't work, all I can say is, try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, i got it to work by removing the import Foundation call. Not sure why that made it work, but at this point im not complaining. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug of Xcode version lower 15.2, I've resolved this problem just added .macOS(.v12) to platforms array in Package.swift of module where I use #Preview

> platforms: [
> .macOS(.v12),
> .iOS(.v15)
> ]

just update Xcode to the latest version, it has to help